# ASP.NET WebAPI - Issues with [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking to implement a new API but rather than going down my usual route of PHP I've opted for C#.

I've had a little play with the 'MVC 4 API' example, but so far I can't seem to get my requests working.

I've created a controller called 'Values' and have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    string body = value;
}
```

I've then sent the following POST request via fiddler to said API:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:56501
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

value=test
```

After running this, it looks as though the method is being called, but when attempting to get the 'value' sent through the body, it doesn't seem to pick up on it and instead gives me a null.

Comment: Can you try using debugger to see what you are getting in Request.Form? For me it usually helps to see, what I'm doing wrong :) `var x = Request.Form;`, breakpoint on that/next line, hover mouse over and click through the object to see what's in it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to make it work for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but this should work meanwhile :)

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:56501
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

"test"
```

---

So I found out that if you need to make it work with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you only need to pass `=value` as the body of your request. Definitely weird, but I guess this is not MVC, it's WebApi, so you shouldn't be passing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` anyway ;)

Comment: This does work, yes, but ideally I'd like to keep it named. Thanks for that though, this will come in handy in the future :-)

Comment: If you really want it named, you can create a viewModel, with only one property, and remove the `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: I think with what you've contributed you've given me enough information to use a JSON object as opposed to the form-encoded post. Thanks for that!